# Debugging a Nordic MCU (feather NRF52) using Segger J-Link

Tags: debugging, nrf51

I have an Afafruit NRF52 board with SD 132 and 5.1 dual fw bootloader.
I implemented RTT logging and controlling (input) and the code is compiled using arduinoBuilder with RTT and debug level 3.
The device uses to control DALI lights but sometimes it hangs, I can see that it does not responses to input and light level never changes.

I want to debug it, maybe getting a stacktrace to see where it hangs, hoping it's a software issue.

Any leads on how to do that ? 
Tutorial maybe ?

Comment: OpenOCD appears to support both the nRF51 and the JLink.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/) supports both the nRF52 and the JLink.  Something like (on Linux):

```
openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/jlink.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/target/nrf52.cfg
```

might start OpenOCD.

You can then connect with (nRF52 flavour of) gdb (arm-none-eabi-gdb).

You can find information about using gdb with OpenOCD [here](http://openocd.org/doc/html/GDB-and-OpenOCD.html) and [here](http://openocd.org/doc/html/General-Commands.html).

Comment: i was told i can use it with openocd and eclipse mcu plugin which is nice, but j-link supposed to be much more with his ozone debugger. i just didn't figure out yet how to debug the code with it or how to use the jlinkexe CLI tool to get a stacktrace, or even how to point it to the debug symbols, and of course i compiled with arduino ide so i have no clue where the debug symbols are, i assumenot in the *.bin\*.hex files....

Comment: and it's feather nrf52 no nrf51 the 51 tag is because i had to put a tag and  there is not nrf52...

Comment: Just change 51 to 52 then. OpenOCD supports both.

Comment: according to openocd it doesn't support non stop mode. i want to debug a running target, i'll explain. the atget seems to be "stack" doesn't responds, however if i use jlink commander and use halt then go presumably i didn't do much, stopped the cpu then resumed it, however it does causes restart and then i don't know what happen. i need to get a stacktrace or get the PC to be sure the cpu indeed doesn't stop...

Comment: Then it sounds like you will be using proprietary Nordic Semiconductor tools to do the job, and we can't help you with that.

Comment: bummer :-( maybe i'll go for gdbserver method, for that iu need to see how to convert the project from aduino to eclipse mcu or Segger's "Ozeone"